# how to add more than one additional conf file in application.conf in scala

Tags: scala, configuration, akka

Hi I am trying to create additional conf files and include them in application.conf but when I try to fetch the values from the second conf file i got this error

```
com.typesafe.config.ConfigException$Missing: No configuration setting found for key 'directUserReadMongoActor-dispatcher'
com.typesafe.config.ConfigException$Missing: No configuration setting found for key 'directUserReadMongoActor-dispatcher'
```

here is my application.conf file

```
include "DirectUserWriteMongoActor"
include "DirectUserReadMongoActor"

akka {
   loggers = ["akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLogger"]
   loglevel = "DEBUG"

}
```

here is my first conf file named "DirectUserWriteMongoActor"

```
akka {
  actor{

    ############################### Setting for a Router #####################################              
    directUserWritwMongoActor-dispatcher {
     # Dispatcher is the name of the event-based dispatcher
         type = Dispatcher
  # What kind of ExecutionService to use
    executor = "fork-join-executor"
  # Configuration for the fork join pool
  fork-join-executor {
    # Min number of threads to cap factor-based parallelism number to
    parallelism-min = 2
    # Parallelism (threads) ... ceil(available processors * factor)
    parallelism-factor = 2.0
    # Max number of threads to cap factor-based parallelism number to
    parallelism-max = 10
  }
  # Throughput defines the maximum number of messages to be
  # processed per actor before the thread jumps to the next actor.
  # Set to 1 for as fair as possible.
  throughput = 10         
                  } #end default-dispatcher 
     ############################### Setting for a Router #####################################              
     deployment{
     /directUserWritwMongoActorRouter{
     router = round-robin
     nr-of-instances = 5
     }
     }#end deployment

   }  #end Actor
}  #end Akka
```

and here is my second conf file "DirectUserReadMongoActor"

```
akka {
  actor{
    ############################### Setting for a Router #####################################              
    directUserReadMongoActor-dispatcher {
     # Dispatcher is the name of the event-based dispatcher
         type = Dispatcher
  # What kind of ExecutionService to use
    executor = "fork-join-executor"
  # Configuration for the fork join pool
  fork-join-executor {
    # Min number of threads to cap factor-based parallelism number to
    parallelism-min = 2
    # Parallelism (threads) ... ceil(available processors * factor)
    parallelism-factor = 2.0
    # Max number of threads to cap factor-based parallelism number to
    parallelism-max = 10
  }
  # Throughput defines the maximum number of messages to be
  # processed per actor before the thread jumps to the next actor.
  # Set to 1 for as fair as possible.
  throughput = 10         
                  } #end default-dispatcher 
     ############################### Setting for a Router #####################################              
     deployment{
     /directUserReadMongoActorRouter{
     router = round-robin
     nr-of-instances = 5
     }
     }#end deployment

   }  #end Actor
}  #end Akka
```

and here is my code in scala object

```
val config = ConfigFactory.load().getConfig("akka.actor")
      println("throughput is "+config.getString("directUserWritwMongoActor-dispatcher.throughput"))
      println("throughput is of read "+config.getString("directUserReadMongoActor-dispatcher.throughput"))
```

the problem is in second `println` line beacuse when i comment this second `println` line the value of `directUserWritwMongoActor-dispatcher.throughput` displayed successfuly but not for  `directUserReadMongoActor-dispatcher.throughput`

i want to print both values please help me where i am doing wrong

Comment: Can you replicate the problem with a simpler scenario? Removing all the unnecessary details, simplifications and renaming for better clarity would be nice. Then it will be easier for others to help. In most cases this also leads to narrowing down the problem and you even might find the root cause yourself.

Comment: Looks like a problem with filenames

Comment: i just figured out the problem i forgot to add the .conf extension at the end of my second conf filename DirectUserReadMongoActor